# Do inherited keys need some kind of creation in SQL creation scripts?

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, database-scripts

I'm trying to represent inheritance (I know) in creating a database. I have it figured out, but I'm not sure if I need to represent the PK that my tables inherit when creating tables.

I have a FoodClass relation with the PK FoodClassID from which DonorFood and CharityFood inherit. Do I need to do anything other than just name the PK FoodClassID in each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you'll want a combination of PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE DonorFood
(FoodClassID INT NOT NULL
 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FoodClass (FoodClassID)
 PRIMARY KEY,
... other columns    );
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure what the semantics of it were. This will still make it a unique number in DonorFood, right?

Comment: Also, would I need to give the constraint a name in this context?

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY constraint means that FoodClassId must be unique. Best practice is to give names to all your constraints but I left the names out just for the sake of brevity.